# Fail to insert data without any error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

currently i'm facing a very strange issue during my c# & asp.net web OOP learning. 
I've wrote the code for insert data to Microsoft Access, no matter how i try the data will never insert into my DB, although the code is correct.

Somehow in other project i'm using the same method to doing is works...
Wish somebody can help here. Thank You.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
public class DataBaseCon
{
    private static OleDbConnection GetConn()
    {
        string ConString;
        ConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪C:\Users\user\Desktop\YogaDB.accdb";
        return new OleDbConnection(ConString);
    }

    public static void Register(string un, string pw, DateTime dob, int ye, string hissue, string email, string contact)
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConn();
        string myQuery = "INSERT INTO User( Username, Password, DateOfBirth, YogaExp, HealthIssue, Email, Contact, UserType) VALUES ( '" + un + "' , '" + pw + "' , '" + dob + "' , '" + ye + "', '" + hissue + "' , '" + email + "', '" + contact + "', 'student')";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Button Function here:

```
protected void RegisterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string un = TextBox1.Text;
            string pw = TextBox2.Text;
            DateTime dob = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
            int ye = int.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
            string hissue = TextBox5.Text;
            string email = TextBox6.Text;
            string contact = TextBox7.Text;
            DataBaseCon.Register(un, pw, dob, ye, hissue, email, contact);
            Label8.Text = "Congratulation "+ un +" , success to register!";
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: **warning** yoru code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: any exception, error? and did you debug  Register method?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);` will not do much if you run this inside IIS or the Dev webserver. Maybe use a Trace.WriteLine to at least see something in the debugger.

Comment: yea i haven't don't any filter yet will proceed after this issue fixed @DanielA.White Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use command parameters it will protect you from Sql Injection and also you will avoid problems like this. User is reserved word in the `Access`, so you should escape it like this `[User]`.

```
string myQuery = @"
               INSERT INTO 
                    [User] ( Username, [Password], DateOfBirth, YogaExp, HealthIssue, Email, Contact, UserType) 
               VALUES ( @UserName, @Password, @DateOfBirth, @YogaExp, @HealthIssue, @Email, @Contact, @UserType)";

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", un);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pw);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dob );
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YogaExp", ye );    
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HealthIssue", hissue );  
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email );    
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", contact ); 
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", "student");
```

Be aware there is no named parameters in `OleDbCommand`, so you **MUST** define the parameters in same order as in the query !

Here is the [**Reserved words in MS Access**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) -> `User` is part of them, so you should escape it !

Remove this part of your code, you are eating your exceptions !

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
}
```

Write it like this:

```
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

**EDIT**: Like @GordThompson said `Password` is reserved word too, so you should escape it too !

Comment: Your solution helps the OP in securing his approach from sql injection. Does it solve the exception as well which he is facing?

Comment: Yes his problem is not escaping the [User]

Comment: @mybirthname i've tried use [User] just now, it still failed to insert into my access database.

Comment: @JakeCube add the parameters like I wrote ... Also write what not happen, what is your exception ?

Comment: currently i tried change table name, also use the parameters that you wrote, still failed to insert to my access DB without any error.

Comment: Use debug and go line by line. Try to insert the query into db.

Comment: `PASSWORD` is a reserved word, too.

Comment: @JakeCube escape Password too.

Comment: @JakeCube you can get a faster resolution to your problem  if you can post the text of the exception you are getting.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in WEBAPPCW.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

@RBT